# Path lifting function associated to a fibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $E\rightarrow B$ be a fibration. It is well-known that this ensures that the map $PE\rightarrow PB×_BE$ has a section. What condition would ensure that this section can be choosen to lift constant paths to constant paths?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if and only if the fiber is totally path disconnected.  For instance, the projection from the product with of the base space  with the pseudoarc has your property whereas the projection from the product with the interval does not.